# Using a Oracle Table in MSSQL

Tags: oracle11g, sql-server-2017

Simply, I have a web project which is using MSSQL 2017 and I need to use "USER" table which is stored in Oracle 11g database. Both project is currently using with own constraints. I think, I create a link between these db's.
 If any data modified in Oracle "USER" table, it should be update in MSSQL as well. 
What should I do in this situation ?

Comment: create a linked server; don't * take a copy of the data

Comment: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4396/creating-a-sql-server-2014-linked-server-for-an-oracle-11g-database/

Comment: @MitchWheat I created my linked server. I need to map oracle user table to my local mssql user table. Is there any way to do this ?